# stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString doesn't fire JavaScript

Tags: javascript, objective-c, cocoa, webview

when I press the up key in my web view, it logs it but it doesn't fire the JS alert as defined in `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString`, any ideas? Thanks

```
 - (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
    {
        [webView setMainFrameURL:@"http://google.com"];
        [webView setAutoresizingMask:NSViewWidthSizable | NSViewHeightSizable];

    }

     -(id)init {
        if( !(self = [super init]) ){
            return nil;
        }

        NSEvent * (^monitorHandler)(NSEvent *);
        monitorHandler = ^NSEvent * (NSEvent * theEvent){

            switch ([theEvent keyCode]) {
                case 123:    // Left arrow
                    NSLog(@"Left behind.");
                    break;
                case 124:    // Right arrow
                    NSLog(@"Right as always!");
                    break;
                case 125:    // Down arrow
                    NSLog(@"Downward is Heavenward");
                    break;
                case 126:    // Up arrow
                    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"alert('yo')"];
                    NSLog(@"Up, up, and away!");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            // Return the event, a new event, or, to stop 
            // the event from being dispatched, nil
            return theEvent;
        };

        // Creates an object we do not own, but must keep track
        // of so that it can be "removed" when we're done
        eventMon = [NSEvent addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:NSKeyDownMask 
                                                         handler:monitorHandler];

        return self;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `WebView` will not display JavaScript alerts by default. In fact, you need to implement the code to display JavaScript alerts yourself, by setting an object as the delegate of the `WebView` and implementing the

[`‑webView:runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage:initiatedByFrame:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Protocols/WebUIDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

delegate method.

However, in your case there's absolutely no reason to do this, since you can simply create a standard [`NSAlert`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSAlert_Class/Reference/Reference.html). I don't understand why you're trying to make the `WebView` display the alert. Why not just display it directly?